# Flutter signed apk uanble to open in android phone

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, signed-apk

I have just signed my flutter apk and tried to test it but whenever I open it , it just gets stuck into launcher background it is not even launching splash screen and it is showing no error

Comment: I had this issue in beta channel. I downgraded flutter to 1.24.0-10.2.pre that resolved it.

Comment: Thank you..it worked for me I just upgraded my flutter version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is with flutter 1.24.0 so I just upgraded my flutter version and everything is working perfectly fine